# Sunspot: facets on location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot, facet

I know it's possible to do stuff like that:

```
bod = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
facet :start_time do
    row :past do
        with(:from).less_than bod - 1.day
    end
    row :today do
        with :from, bod
    end
end
```

So I tried to add facets on the location like this:

```
with(:coordinates).near(coord[0], coord[1], :precision => 3)
facet :distance do
    row 2 do
        with(:coordinates).near(coord[0], coord[1], :precision => 2)
    end
    row 3 do
        with(:coordinates).near(coord[0], coord[1], :precision => 3)
    end
end
```

But I get the following error: `undefined method near for #<Sunspot::DSL::Restriction:[...]>`. Why is it not a Sunspot::DSL::RestrictionWithNear?

If you got facets with locations working, please, help me ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: switch to ElasticSearch <3 http://www.elasticsearch.org/